# MVC: DataTable doesn't refresh on ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to refresh the DataTable data when the JSON success comes back from my controller when performing CRUD operations. The CRUD operations work fine and the toastr success message appears, I just can't seem to get the Datatable to refresh on the operations when the modal closes. I don't want to do a location.reload() because the data entered on the rest of the page will be lost. I am using partial views for the modals and not sure if that has something to do with my issue or not. I have researched and tried several things but can't get it to work.

Code:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateFooterLink(footer_links footer_link)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.footer_links.Add(footer_link);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Link Successfully." },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return View("_CreateFooterLink", footer_link);                               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new { ErrorMessage = ex.Message, Success = false },
                ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet
            };
        }
    }

      @model WST___Dev.Models.footer_links
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Add New Link</h3>
        </div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "CreateLink" }))

        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.name, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3 required"})
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name, new { @class = "form-control", id="name"})
                                <div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.name)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.target_url, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3 required" })
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.target_url, new { @class = "form-control", id="target_url" })
                                <div>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.target_url)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSubmit" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        }
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });      
                $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var name = $('#name').val();
                    var target_url = $('#target_url').val();
                    var JSONObject = {
                        name: name,
                        target_url: target_url
                    };
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("CreateFooterLink", "StyleEditor")',
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify(JSONObject),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.success == true) {
                                $("#MyModal").modal('hide');
                                toastr.success(result.message);
                                //window.location.reload(true);
                                //setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 6);
                                //setInterval(function () {
                                //    table.ajax.reload();
                                //}, 3)
                                //table.draw();
                                //table.fnClearTable();
                                //table.fnAddData();
                                //table.fnDraw();
                                //var oTableToUpdate = $(tblLinks).dataTable({ bRetrieve: true });
                                //$oTableToUpdate.fnAddData();
                                //$oTableToUpdate.fnDraw();


                            } else {
                                $("#MyModal").modal('show');
                                toastr.error(result.ErrorMessage);
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (xml, message, text) {
                            toastr.error("Msg: " + message + ", Text: " + text);
                        }
                    });

                });
            });
        </script>
```

DataTable initialization:

```
 var table;
$(document).ready(function () {

    table = $('#tblLinks').DataTable({
        "ordering": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "orderMulti": false,
        "deferRender": true,
        "pageLength": 5,
        'columnDefs': [{
            'targets': 2,
            'title': '',
            'sortable': false,
        }],
        "stateSave": true,
        "stateDuration": -1,
    });          
});
```

Comment: You should give a brief synopsis of what you tried and what result you got.

Comment: I got it work but I have action links in the 3rd col (edit/delete) and it doesn't add them for the new row. @jdv

Comment: Details about what you want, what you have tried, and what results you got should go in the body of the question. Comments can be deleted, which make the question less useful over time.